# Why is my macro's form not evaluated before function invocation?

Tags: macros, clojure

I have the following Clojure code:

```
(defn mul [a b]
  (* a b))

(defmacro create-my-macro [macroname]
    `(defmacro ~macroname [a# b#]
      (mul a# b#)))

(create-my-macro my-mul)

(my-mul 1 2)
;; => 2
(my-mul (+ 1 1) 2)
;; => ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

I get the answer I want when I wrap the arguments in the invocation of `mul` with `eval`:

```
(mul (eval #a) (eval #b))
```

But I don't understand why it is necessary to do that: if the `my-mul` macro had been defined directly (and not through another macro), it would work. For example, the following works fine:

```
(defmacro my-mul [a b] `(mul ~a ~b))
(my-mul (+ 1 1) 2)
;; => 4
```

Why am I seeing this behavior?

---

**Edit:** In response to a comment, below are the macroexpands for the failing case (i.e., without using `eval`):

```
(macroexpand '(create-my-macro my-mul))
;; => (do
;;      (clojure.core/defn my-mul 
;;        ([&form &env a__58__auto__ b__59__auto__] 
;;          (foo/mul a__58__auto__ b__59__auto__)))
;;      (. (var my-mul) (setMacro)) (var my-mul))

(macroexpand '(my-mul (+ 1 1) 2))
;; => ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.multiply (Numbers.java:146)
```

Comment: Debug hint: what does macroexpand show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you show, the code you'd like to emit looks like:

```
(defmacro my-mul [a b] `(mul ~a ~b))
```

So you need to syntax-quote it and suffix all locals with #:

```
`(defmacro my-mul [a# b#] `(mul ~a# ~b#))
```

Thus you macro-emitting macros should be:

```
(defmacro create-my-macro [macroname]
    `(defmacro ~macroname [a# b#]
       `(mul ~a# ~b#)))
```

Comment: Yeah, your answer is more detailed than my one :)

Answer (score 2):

```
(defmacro create-my-macro [macroname]
 `(defmacro ~macroname [a# b#]
   `(mul ~a# ~b#)))
```